# Trying to start Liferay with Tomcat I get this Java ConnectException: Connection Refused. Any suggestions?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, liferay

```
Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2820)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:148)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
14:23:57,798 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0][BasicResourcePool:1841] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@2a391af -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (3). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:
```

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

```
java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt


at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2744)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:148)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Comment: Can you set your language to English and re-trigger the exception?

Comment: Do you have mysql running at all? The error message says that Liferay can't connect to mysql. Thus either your database connection is not correctly configured (like Artem Khojoyan suggests) or not existing/running at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a MySQL connection problem. Check your db connection settings, username/password, url, etc. Should be something like this:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/lportal
jdbc.default.username=mysqluser
jdbc.default.password=mysqlpass
```

A common URL looks like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false&autoReconnect=true
```